# How to remove instances that are not aligned perfectly to the normal

Tags: geometry-nodes, normals, instances

I'm trying to distribute instances of a cube around the cube, I aligned them to the normal of the base mesh, but I can't figure out how to remove instances that in the edges of the cube.

[image: instances of cube in the edges]

One clue that could help is when I use the normal to scale the instances it seems to only choose the problematic instances.

[image: using the normal to scale the instances]

From what I understand, this happens because perfectly aligned normal have at least 1 of their XYZ coordinates to zero, scaling one of their components to zero essentially removes them.

Answer (score 0):

While writing this, I figured out cumbersome a way to accomplish by comparing the normal of the vertices to zero. If 2 of the normals are zero then select it.

[image: Removing vertices Solution]

Is there a better way to do this? I feel like this solution is cumbersome